# Unexpected Behavior of Date Parse on Azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, azure

In short, I'm parsing a passed in date to get a date to be used in an EF query.  It works as expected when testing locally, and reports it as the correct date minus one day when hosted in Azure.

The string form is `11/27/2013`

To convert to dates I'm using:

```
var sDate = DateTime.Parse("11/27/2013").Date;
var eDate = sDate.AddDays(1);
```

Then in EF I'm using:

```
var res = from p in context.Table
          where p.PlaceholderDate >= sDate &&
          p.PlaceholderDate < eDate
          select p;
```

I end up with data for `11/26/2013` when hosted on Azure, and `11/27/2013` on my local machine.

If helpful, my timezone is EST.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you pass a US culture into the DateTime.Parse?

Comment: What's the timezone at your azure machine? Did you try parsing date in such way: DateTime.Parse("11/27/2013", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal); ?

Comment: This is because in Windows Azure the default timezone is UTC.

Comment: @GauravMantri, what effect does that have on my example? If I create a `DateTime` in a UTC environment, it should be 11/27/2013 in this case right?

Comment: You're right. That should not have any impact as far as parsing the date is concerned. I just tried parsing the date using PowerShell in Windows Azure VM and it did not change the date. Could it be that EF is doing some conversion on its end?

Comment: How about DateTime.ParseExact with a format of "MM/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: Is the database your are querying the same in both cases? I mean are you querying the database in the cloud also when you test from your local machine? If not, try to and check if you get the same unexpected behavior. In this way you can confirm whether the problem is in EF/Azure or in the target db/engine.

Comment: It's the same. I make my calls to the same server even when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give DateTimeOffset.Parse a try? And then pass in the expected offset (change the +1:00 to whatever offset you require) just to be safe?

Like so?

```
// String with date and offset 
dateString = "05/01/2008 +1:00";
offsetDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString);
Console.WriteLine(offsetDate.ToString());
```